# In C++ standard, Why Infinite loop occurs when i use list.begin() as list.splice()'s first and third parameters at the same time

Tags: c++, list, splice

When I use begin() as list.splice()'s first and third parameters at the same time,
I don't know why output has infinite loop.

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    list<int> mylist;
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        mylist.push_back(i);
    mylist.splice(mylist.begin(), mylist, mylist.begin(), mylist.end());

    for (auto it = mylist.begin(); it != mylist.end(); it++) {
        cout << *it << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: What compiler are you using? VS 2015 does not loop forever.

Comment: ["__Data races__
Both the container and x are modified.
Concurrently accessing or modifying their elements is safe, although iterating x or ranges that include position is not."](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/splice/) You are iterating a range that includes `position`. Also "This effectively inserts those elements into the container and removes them from x, altering the sizes of both containers" (same source), so what the heck do you expect to happen there? `myList` (the parameter one) is supposed to be empty after this call.

Comment: @grek40 I agree that the whole idea of splicing a list into itself is dumb and should not work, but I can't find any reference to what exactly should happen here. also how is it a concurrent access if there is only 1 thread?

Comment: @Ap31 the second part is the important one: "although iterating x or ranges that include position is not". By giving the same iterator for 1st and 3rd parameter, this is violated, because most likely, the 3rd parameter will be used for iterating.

Comment: @grek40 this part seems to be about concurrent access, and not about method usage. What it seems to imply is "you can modify elements from another thread concurrently with `list::splice` call, but you cannot iterate" - makes sence, but has nothing to do with this specific question

Comment: @Ap31 You are right. Reading on to other sections was a better idea than looking at the data race section.

Answer (score 1):

The code exhibits undefined behavior:

> **Exception safety**
>
> (...)
>   [if (...) position is in the range [first,last) in (3), it causes undefined behavior](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/splice/).

That doesn't exactly explain why the infinite loop occurs but it explains why an infinite loop is a possible behavior.